# Run Python from VBA in other directory

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to run a python script from VBA and all works fine now as the excel file is in the same directory as the python script, my code is :

```
Sub forecast()
    RunPython ("import Forecast; Forecast.data_forecast()")
End Sub
```

However I now want to move the excel file to a separate path and can't figure out how to direct it to the correct path ('I:\Forecasting Model') despite looking at numerous other posts.

Thanks in advance, Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.chdir` to change the current working directory of your python script

```
import os

os.chdir(r'I:\Forecasting Model')

import Forecast

#... more code
```

Comment: Is there a way to preferably do this via VBA at all?